# PHP wrong phpsessid

Tags: php, session, redirect

I have a site where sometimes users get incorrect session data. I've been testing it login with two different users quickly. I discovered that when user A gets user's B session data the phpsessid from session_id() is not equal to the PHPSESSID cookie in the browser.

The code is something like this:

login.php

```
if(isset($_POST['uname']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
    $logged = login($_POST['uname'],$_POST['password']);
    if($logged){
        header( 'Location: index.php' ) ;
        exit();
    }
}    

function login($uname,$password){
    $user = check_db_user($uname,$password)
    if($user){
        session_regenerate_id(TRUE);
        $_SESSION["name"] = $user->name;
        ...
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

The login works fine. In index.php is where I see the problem of the wrong session data. If it occurs I only have to reload the page and it renders the correct session data. So, the problem I think it is the redirect to index.php that is not sending the correct php session id. I have tried adding

```
header("Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=" . session_id() . "; path=/");
```

before the redirect but it still doesn´t work.

Logout.php

```
session_start();
$_SESSION = array();
if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
    $params = session_get_cookie_params();
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,$params["path"],
    $params["domain"],$params["secure"], $params["httponly"]);
}
session_destroy();
session_regenerate_id(TRUE);
header('location:login.php');
```

Comment: Can you explain how the following scenaro occurs: "I discovered that when user A gets user's B session data the phpsessid from session_id() is not equal to the PHPSESSID cookie in the browser."

Comment: You did your test with two different browsers, didn't you?

Comment: @ForguesR It happens in IE7 and Chrome. 
First I login with user A, then quickly logout and login with user B. I repeat this until it fails.

Comment: You mut use `session_destroy();` on logout of the user. Then something like this never happens.

Comment: @jankal I added my logout file.

Comment: OK. Does it work now how you're expecting it?

Comment: @jankal As a workaround I replaced the redirect with a refresh after 3 sec and added a check to redirect to index if the user is already logged in. Now it shows correct session data but sometimes It doesn't log in and i have to do it twice.

Comment: OK. @Madzergling This should be ok like this.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have several holes in your authentication.

1. I do not see a session_start(); in your login processing section.
2. there should be filtering of form passed parameters.
3. I think you are storing username in $_SESSION without encoding. That is also a security risk.

here is the code I used to use. Sorry, if there is a copy/cut/paste error.
Note: I validate my inputs before calling login().

```
    <?php
    define("YOUR_COOKIE,",  'your_bakery' );
    define("HASH_SALT",  'your_salt' );

    function login( $uname, $passwd ) {
        $loginIsOK = FALSE;
        $this->userInfo = dbUser( $uname );
        if ( ! empty( $this->userInfo ) &&
             ( $this->userInfo['pwd'] == sha1( $passwd.HASH_SALT ) ) ) {

            $this->userInfo['hashedUsername'] = sha1( $uname.HASH_SALT );
            $ses_id = session_id();
            $hour = time() + 46000; //1hour = 3600                                  

            setcookie( YOUR_COOKIE, $this->userInfo['hashedUsername'], $hour );
            $xtd=getdate();
            $this->userInfo['lastLogin'] = date('Y-M-d H:i:s',$xtd[0]);
            $this->userInfo['loginCount'] = $this->userInfo['loginCount'] + 1;
            $this->userInfo['sessionId'] = $ses_id;
            dbUserUpdate( $this->userInfo );
            $loginIsOK = TRUE;
        }
        return( $loginIsOK );
    }

    // for the login check:                                                         
    function isLogedIn() {
        if ( empty( $this->userInfo ) )
            return false;
        $ses_id = session_id();
        if ( empty( $this->userInfo['sessionId']) ) {
            return false;
        }
        else if ( $ses_id != $this->userInfo['sessionId'] )  {
            $xLoginColision = $this->userInfo['sessionIdCollisions'] + 1;
            $this->userInfo['sessionIdCollisions'] = $xLoginColision;
            dbUserUpdate( $this->userInfo );
            return false;
        }
        else
            return true;
    }

// Then for logout the only thing needed is:                                    
$past = time() - 100;  //this makes the time in the past to destroy the cookie  
setcookie( YOUR_COOKIE, $past );
//you can also change the session id.
```

I hope this helps.